# Using R to create a table from a list while preserving attributes

Tags: r, list, bioconductor

I am trying to use R to create a table that links all KEGG orthology IDs to all related Entrez genes. In theory this can be done using the KEGGREST package from bioconductor.

I have a list of all the KEGG orthology IDs, ko_nums, which I want to convert to Entrez IDs using the function keggConv. First I try lapply, but this is a problem because the url query is too long:

```
 library(KEGGREST)
 lapply(ko_nums,keggLink("genes",ko_nums))
 Error in .get Url: (414) Request-URI Too Long
```

So that won't work with a query as big as mine. I tried to expand the list and query one at a time using:

```
 output = apply(expand.grid(ko_nums),1,
              function(x,y) keggLink("genes",x[1]))
```

But if you do this with a toy where

```
 ko_nums = c("ko:K00001","ko:K00002","ko:K00003")
 output = apply(expand.grid(ko_nums),1,
              function(x,y) keggLink("genes",x[1]))
 output
```

you see that my output is a list of three, with many genes per orthology ID in a list. I want to keep each gene paired with its respective orthology number in a data table, BUT 
a) wrapping this in an "unlist" function removes all the ko identifiers, and 
b) I can't make a dataframe with the list as it is because each row would have a different number of elements.

Is there a way to make a two-column table from this list in which the ko numbers are split into individual orthology/gene pairs? Like this:

```
 ko:K00001     gene_1
 ko:k00001     gene_2
 ko:K00001     gene_3
 ko:K00002     gene_4
 ko:K00002     gene_5
 ko:K00002     gene_6
```

etc.

Comment: Your original attempt, `lapply(ko_nums,keggLink("genes",ko_nums))` is not doing what you think it is; try `lapply(ko_nums, keggLink, target="genes")` or better, split `ko_nums` into chunks. If you want more help, make your example reproducible (by providing a short vector of valid `ko_nums`).

Comment: I provided a toy where 'ko_nums = c("ko:K00001","ko:K00002","ko:K00003")'. The original attempt does in fact work with this subset, returning a list of three. I assume that this was because the url length for this query is acceptable in R KEGGREST. Splitting the ko_nums variable will certainly work, but I can't believe that there is no way to preserve list attributes in R to save in a vector or dataframe, as I have indicated in my desired output.

I tried using 'lapply(ko_nums, keggLink, target="genes")', but I am getting a "subscript out of bounds" error message.

Answer (score 2):

Split your long list of `ko_nums` into groups of, say, `n=1000` identifiers (choosing `n` so that the URL is not too long)

```
n = 1000
k = length(ko_nums)
grp = floor((1:k - 1) / n)
ko_groups = split(ko_nums, grp)
```

Apply `keggLink()` to each group

```
res = lapply(ko_groups, keggLink, target="genes")
```

Combine the results into the desired from

```
df = data.frame(ko_num=unlist(sapply(res, names)),
                value = unname(unlist(res)))
```